# How to use string.substr() function?

Tags: c++, string, substring

I want to make a program that will read some number in string format and output it like this: if the number is 12345 it should then output 12 23 34 45 . I tried using the substr() function from the c++ string library, but it gives me strange results - it outputs 1 23 345 45 instead of the expected result. Why ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    string a;
    cin >> a;
    string b;
    int c;

    for(int i=0;i<a.size()-1;++i)
    {
        b = a.substr(i,i+1);
        c = atoi(b.c_str());
        cout << c << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [`atoi` shouldn't be used](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If I am correct, the second parameter of [`substr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) should be the length of the substring. How about

```
b = a.substr(i,2);
```

?

Comment: Yeah, he's incrementing the length of the substring each time.

Answer (score 26):

As shown [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/), the second argument to `substr` is the *length*, not the ending position:

> `string substr ( size_t pos = 0, size_t n = npos ) const;`
>
> *Generate substring*
>
> Returns a string object with its contents initialized to a substring of the current object. This substring is the character sequence that starts at character position `pos` and has a length of `n` characters.

Your line `b = a.substr(i,i+1);` will generate, for values of `i`:

```
substr(0,1) = 1
substr(1,2) = 23
substr(2,3) = 345
substr(3,4) = 45  (since your string stops there).
```

What you need is `b = a.substr(i,2);`

You should also be aware that your output will look funny for a number like 12045. You'll get `12 20 4 45` due to the fact that you're using `atoi()` on the string section and outputting that integer. You might want to try just outputing the string itself which *will* be two characters long:

```
b = a.substr(i,2);
cout << b << " ";
```

In fact, the entire thing could be more simply written as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(void) {
    string a;
    cin >> a;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size() - 1; i++)
        cout << a.substr(i,2) << " ";
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another interesting variant question can be:

How would you make `"12345"` as `"12 23 34 45"` without using another string?

Will following do?

```
    for(int i=0; i < a.size()-1; ++i)
    {
        //b = a.substr(i, 2);
        c = atoi((a.substr(i, 2)).c_str());
        cout << c << " ";
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`substr(i,j)` means that you start from the index `i` (assuming the first index to be 0) and take next `j` chars.
It does not mean going up to the index `j`.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the above output using following code in c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
  char *str;
  clrscr();
  printf("\n Enter the string");
  gets(str);
  for(int i=0;i<strlen(str)-1;i++)
  {
    for(int j=i;j<=i+1;j++)
      printf("%c",str[j]);
    printf("\t");
  }
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which is exactly what you _shouldn't_ be doing: http://powerfield-software.com/?p=829

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution without using `substr()`

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;


int main() {
    string c="12345";
    int p=0;

    for(int i=0;i<c.length();i++) {
        cout<<c[i];
        p++;

        if (p % 2 == 0 && i != c.length()-1) {
            cout<<" "<<c[i];
            p++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The string constructor can be used to get a copy of a substring.

```
string(const string& str, size_t pos, size_t n)
```

For example...

```
b = string(a, i, 2); // substring of a from position i, including 2 characters
```

This differs from `substr` in that the length n cannot be omitted. I offer this only as an alternative, not as an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible solution with string_view**

```
void do_it_with_string_view( void )
{
    std::string a { "12345" };
    for ( std::string_view v { a }; v.size() - 1; v.remove_prefix( 1 ) )
        std::cout << v.substr( 0, 2 ) << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```