# Indexing issue of C++ string substr function

Tags: c++, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ string.substr() function problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477850/c-string-substr-function-problem)

```
string s = "0123456789";

cout<<s.substr(0,4)<<endl;

cout<<s.substr(4,7)<<endl;
```

The output of the above lines of code was pretty unexpected , s.substr(0,4) gave me "0123", s.substr(4,7) gave me "456789" . It was expecting only "456" . Am I missing something here , and is there any alternative to substr function in C++ , which would give me only "456" on the second call.

Comment: This is definitely a dupe, but I can't find it.

Comment: @JohnDibling This one is the exact same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477850/c-string-substr-function-problem I'll vote to close as duplicate.

Comment: @jogojapan:  That's not the one I was thinking of, but it will do.

Comment: @jogojapan: I got my answer anyway . So thanks.

Comment: @JohnDibling: No offense , the problem was so simple , nobody would want to look at the complicated example jogojapan suggested . So , I would request for the example to stay here , the usage of substr() function is not obvious to all at first glance .

Comment: @MotiurRahman:  The dupe I was trying to remember was an *exact* duplicate of the posted question.  And, no offense, but the use of `substr` is quite obvious if you read the documentation and not try to guess.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr

Comment: @JohnDibling: Okay , well flag it then .

Comment: I voted to close as a dupe already.  Flagging for moderator attention isn't really called for in this case, I don't think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd parameter of `substr` is the count of symbols, not the end index as you assume. You shall use `substr(4,3)`.

Answer (score 5):

The second argument of `substr` is the length of the desired substring, not the end index. So instead of `s.substr(4,7)`, you want `s.substr(4,3)`.

Answer (score 2):

`substr` takes the initial position and the desired length - see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/).

Try `substr(4,3)`.