# Multiple elements for substr C++

Tags: c++, line, substr

I am working on a function which needs me to take the substring of the first two elements of a line.

> char those = line.substr(0,1);

When I run  the program, it only takes the first element, that's it.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Also, how can I tell C++ to get the following elements from an index until the end of the line?

Comment: read the manual :)  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr

Comment: Repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477850/c-string-substr-function-problem Looks like the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument is [the number of elements to take, not an inclusive index](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr).

Comment: Ok, my next question is: how can I tell C++ to take elements from the index on.

Comment: @JulioGarcia: If you leave off the second argument it will return all characters from the index to the end of the string.